# Converting a collection of subtype to collection of supertype

Tags: java, generics

What's the best way in Java  to convert a collection of a subtype to a collection of a supertype ?

```
class A {}
class B extends A {}

final A a = new B(); // OK.

final Collection<B> bs = Arrays.asList(new B());
final Collection<A> as1 = bs; // <- Error
final Collection<A> as2 = (Collection<A>) (Collection<?>) bs; // <- Unchecked cast warning
final Collection<A> as3 = bs.stream().collect(Collectors.toList()); // Browses through all the elements :-/
```

I have to implement a method (defined in an interface) that returns a `Collection<A>` while the concrete result I get is a `Collection<B>` .

Comment: Why do you want to convert collection of subtype to collection of supertype?

Comment: Collection<A> is not interchangeable with Collection<B> in that way, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47313816/java-generics-in-list-return-type-on-a-method-inherited-from-multiple-interfaces/47314161#47314161  You can add a bunch of B's to a Collection<A> though

Comment: @hellzone Well, I stated it : because of the method signature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way, assuming you don't need to modify the collection through `as1`:

```
Collection<A> as1 = Collections.unmodifiableCollection(bs);
```

If you do need to modify the collection, the only safe thing to do is to copy it:

```
Collection<A> as1 = new ArrayList<>(bs);
```

Comment: I like this because it is clean (and indeed, I do not need to modify the list). But copying or casting : what is the most efficient ?

Comment: @EmmanuelGuiton I believe `Collection<? extends A> as = bs;` is most efficient and safe.

Comment: @VenkataRaju `Collection<A>` is required (not `Collection<? extends A>`).

Comment: @EmmanuelGuiton it is more efficient to cast, because once that cast is done, it's never checked again. If you use the unmodifiableCollection approach, every call to that collection goes through an extra layer of dispatch. It's a question of whether the perceived performance benefits of casting outweigh the risks of losing type safety.

Answer (score -1):

Additional suggestion :

```
public static <A> Collection<A> coerce(final Collection<? extends A> col)
{
    return (Collection<A>) col;
}
```

Comment: There's a reason why Java stops you doing the assignment directly. Circumventing its protections is irresponsible.

Comment: Even if this were the right thing to do, you're using a generic type parameter (`<A>`), so the `A` in this method's signature is not the class `A`. Replace it with `T` and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Indeed this solution works only if the collection is not mutated after the cast. @Michael the type parameter is not the A presented in the question but the solution is nonetheless correct for any subclass relation `S extends T` (albeit omitting mutations)

Comment: @O.Gre it works after casting *if you don't add anything into the collection that wasn't already in the collection (aside from `null`)*. Some mutations can be performed with no problem.

Comment: @O.Gre I didn't say it wouldn't work. It's just misleading.