# Android ArrayList and HashMap issue

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I originally wrote an Android app in 2010 in Eclipse.  I haven't touched the code since then.  I recently wanted to update a few things.  I imported my project into Android Studio.  I initially had gradle version issues and stuff like that to deal with.

My code done in Eclipse was 100% free of errors and warnings.  Now in Android Studio it has all sorts of warnings and errors.  I cleaned up 95% of the warnings and a couple errors due to what I assume is just the evolution of the language and maybe some deprecated methods.

I have the following code that is producing the following error.

```
Error:(129, 79) error: incompatible types: ArrayList<HashMap> cannot be converted to List<? extends Map<String,?>>
```

Can someone point me in the right direction how to simply update this code to the latest and greatest way of doing this?  I originally wrote this for Android 2.3 in 2010 and now trying to compile for Android 4.1.

```
ArrayList<HashMap> list = new ArrayList<HashMap>();

HashMap<String, String> items = new HashMap<String, String>();
items.put("Apple", "Red");
items.put("Orange", "Orange");
items.put("Banana", "Yellow");
items.put("Pear", "Green");
items.put("Grape", "Purple");
list.add(items);

SimpleAdapter sa = new SimpleAdapter(this, (List<? extends Map<String, ?>>) list, R.layout.list_fruit, new String[] {"Apple", "Orange", "Banana", "Pear", "Grape"}, new int[] {R.id.listApple, R.id.listOrange, R.id.listBanana, R.id.listPear, R.id.listGrape}) {};
```

Comment: Does HashMap not need its key/value types defined? `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();`

Comment: Thank you.  The key/values were defined in the following HashMap definition statement and it used to work as is.  Further defining this in the ArrayList worked fine.

Comment: No problem, it's nice when it's a simple fix :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this answer: [Java generics in List return type on a method inherited from multiple interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47313816/java-generics-in-list-return-type-on-a-method-inherited-from-multiple-interfaces/47314161#47314161)

It has some details on why that doesn't work, but basically, another consumer of your ArrayList would blow up if you put a Map-but-not-a-HashMap in the list, which is what `List<? extends Map<String, ?>>` allows.

Try declaring your list as `List<? extends Map<String, ?>>`.  You should generally avoid declaring variables as implementations (ArrayList, HashMap, etc...) and stick to the interfaces (List, Map, etc...) so that you're not coupled to specific implementations.